# How to customize invalid characters for installation directory?

Tags: install4j

I need to customize the characters for the installation directory, which should be invalid. I tried it to check the characters at the validation script and show an error message, but if the user use some default value of the dialog, the default message will be displayed instead the customized one. Now the question: can I customize the invalid characters or maybe can I deactivate the default validation to use the customized one at the validation script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the installation directory selector, the standard validation cannot be disabled.

You could use a form screen with a "Directory chooser" form component. That component has a property named "Standard validation". If you deselect it, the bad characters will not be checked.

Comment: So it is alos not possible to customize the invalid characters? Maybe this could be an improvement for the next version. We need to customize the invalid characters but would like to take the default installation directory dialog to keep the functionalities of variable setting etc..

Comment: I have added a feature request for disabling the standard validation for the installation directory chooser.